# Do action when holding a button from bottom navigation bar

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, bottomnavigationview, android-bottomnav

I wanted to enter a settings page when I hold down the home button on the bottom navigation bar. I looked for how to get the id of a button in the bottom navigation but couldn't find anything.

Do you know if I can get a button from this bar?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
binding.bottomNav.menu.forEach {
        if (it.itemId == R.id.home) {
            binding.bottomNav.findViewById<View>(it.itemId).setOnLongClickListener {

                // your action

                true
            }
        }
    }
```

It iterates through all the menu items of the `BottomNavView` and sets `LongClickListener` for the desired menu item